# After how many days should I reset my JWT cookie for Android local database?

Tags: netezza

I'm currently doing forgot password functionality for the first time and here's the code so far.

sends the email for the user that has the URL with the JWT token

router.post('/change-password', verifyAuth, resetPassword);
receives and confirms JWT then changes password

router.post('/change-password/:token/:password', confirmResetPassword);
the process I'm currently thinking about is in the email I send the user to

http://localhost:3000/change-passowrd?token=TOKEN_VALUE
but I'm not sure if this is a smart idea or not? I can also use cookies if it's better, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to store the JWT token store in the URL for reset password functionality. You have to send this link using Email or any other secure communication service.

I implemented this feature

```
https://yourapp.com/home/reset/${token}

const data = {
  from: "yourcompanymail@outlook.com",
  to: user.email,
  subject: "Please reset your password",
  text: `Hello ${user.name},\n\nI heard that you lost your Teeny password. You can use the following link to reset your password: https://yourapp.com/home/reset/${token}
};

transporter.sendMail(data, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
  }
});
```

Now if the user hits this URL, validate the token and redirect or render the change password page. But don't send the password through the URL.

Comment: Well you need to give it a try!